# Post increment operator override and double post increment

Tags: c++, post-increment

Long story short. This will not work (and I absolutely understand why):

```
int i;
i++++;
```

The compiler says `lvalue required as increment operand`

But this works well:

```
struct A
{
    A operator ++(int)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

A a;
a++++;
```

And I'm confused. Isn't operator overload function returns a rvalue?

Comment: Undefined behavior =)

Comment: This is not undefined behavior. `(expr)++` is interpreted as `operator++((expr), 0)`, and actual function is determined by the mechanism of name resolution and overload resolution. In this case, your `A A::operator++(int)` is an candidate function found by ADL. And this member function is not reference qualified. Then the member function can be selected in overload resolution. If you want the member function not to be selected, just `&` qualify your member function like `A A::operator++ (int) &`. It's like `A operator++ (A &, int)`.

Comment: @akakatak in this case I get `error: no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++'`on gcc 4.9.2

Comment: @nikitablack Yes. That's because `A A::operator++ (int) &` is filtered out from viable functions by overload resolution. `A A::operator++ (int ) &` is like `A operator++ (A &, int)`, and `A &` cannot bind rvalue. In addition, if we can define `int operator++ (int &, int)`, `i++++` is valid. However, operator function overload is allowed only when at least one of parameters is type, reference of type, enum or reference of enum. Then this declaration is not allowed.

Comment: So, the postfix operator for primitive types works differently? At least it have a good error message.